# Creating view on top of a subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a query which fetches the max date time from on column and also the corresponding data of the other columns from the table. But for selecting the max date time I have to use a subquery so that i get the corresponding value of other columns. But since I have used a subquery with an alias I am unable to make a view on top of that. So can my query be modified to give me my desired result and also I am able to make my view with that query.

The sql query which I have made for my requierment is below.It gives me the desired result but I am unable to make a view on top of the query.Hence I am forced to make to separete views to get the desired result. Can the query be modified to give me the result and also I am able to make the view on top of the query.

SELECT SD.a_n, SD.t_c, SD.ppl, date_time FROM (SD JOIN (SELECT SD.t_c, MAX(date_time) AS MDT FROM SD GROUP BY t_c)wn_m_d_t ON (((SD.t_c = wn_m_d_t.t_c) AND (SD.date_time = wn_m_d_t.MDT)))) WHERE ((SD.t_c IN('drep','sred')))

Answer (score 2):

Your query in a bit more readable format is:

```
SELECT SD.a_n, SD.t_c, SD.ppl, date_time
FROM SD JOIN
     (SELECT SD.t_c, MAX(date_time) AS MDT
      FROM SD
      GROUP BY t_c
     ) wn_m_d_t
     ON SD.t_c = wn_m_d_t.t_c AND SD.date_time = wn_m_d_t.MDT
WHERE SD.t_c IN ('drep', 'sred');
```

MySQL has a string restriction that views cannot contain subqueries in the `from` clause.  You seem to want to get the records in `SD` with the most recent date for each `t_c`.  Here is another approach:

```
SELECT SD.a_n, SD.t_c, SD.ppl, SD.date_time
FROM SD
WHERE SD.t_c IN ('drep', 'sred') AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from sd sd2
                  where sd2.t_c = sd.t_c and
                        sd2.date_time > sd.date_time
                 );
```

And, this will work in a view.  Subqueries are allowed in the `select` and `from` clauses.
This says, "Get me all rows in `SD` where there is no record with the same `t_c` and a bigger `date_time`."

Comment: This query is giving the desired result but it is taking very long time to fetch the records. So is there any way to improve it's performance.

Comment: An index on `sd(t_c, date_time)` should help.

Comment: Already index is present on the table on the two columns. But still the query is taking long time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query is possible without using a subquery too.

```
SELECT SD.a_n, SD.t_c, SD.ppl, SD.date_time
FROM SD
LEFT JOIN SD AS sd2
 ON sd2.t_c = SD.t_c
 AND sd2.date_time > SD.date_time   
WHERE SD.t_c IN ('drep', 'sred') AND sd2.t_c IS NULL
```